# How do I put a file under source control?

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

I know this is a simple thing, but I can't find the control for it in Xcode!

I want to do a Commit to Github, but it won't let me as none of my files are under source control.

How do I put my project files under source control?

Comment: You tagged this xcode. Did you read any of the tutorials on using GIT support in XCode?

Answer (score 2):

You can set it up in organizer -> Repositories. This tutorial might be helpful to you: http://www.raywenderlich.com/13771/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-6

Answer (score 2):

To import a project into the source control first you must open the terminal and go into the directory of the project and type:

$ git init

$ git ./*

$ git commit -m "Initial commit"

then in Xcode with open the project and with "shift cmd 2" you access the organizer and there you find the repository control

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use "github mac client"(http://mac.github.com/) which helps you import your project using GUI. It's very easy.

This article might be helpful : http://www.hacheka.com/newbie-guide-for-using-github-in-mac-osx/